# Convert each sublayer in shp.zip to csv files QGIS (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile

I'm trying to convert a shp.zip into several CSV files. This file contains several shapefiles inside, which I want to store each one in one different CSV.

Let's say I have:

```
| - my_polygons_shp.zip
  | adm0.shp
  | adm1.shp
  | adm2.shp
```

(Along with all the .bfs, .cpg, etc.)

In order to do that I'm loading this file straight to QGIS:

```
filepath = "/tmp/my_polygons_shp.zip"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(filepath, "ogr")
```

My full code has a loop through all sublayers but make it simpler. Let's say I just want to load the layer adm1 (so afterwards I can save it as CSV). I tried:

```
uri = "{}/adm1.shp".format(filepath)
sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "ogr")
```

and also:

```
uri = "{}/adm1.shp|layername=adm1".format(filepath)
sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "ogr")
```

In both cases when check if the layer was correctly created with `sub_vlayer.isValid()` says `False`

```
sublayers = layer.dataProvider().subLayers()
for sublayer in sublayers:
    layer_id, layer_name, num_features, geom_type, _, _ = sublayer.split("!!::!!")
    uri = f"{filepath}|layername={layer_name}"
```

I have also tried to export the layer I'm interested in:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    layer, 
    output_filename, 
    "utf-8", 
    layer.crs(), 
    driverName = "CSV" , 
    layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_WKT',f'LAYER_NAME=adm1',,f'GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom'])
```

This one creates the CSV file, however it uses the first layer instead of the one I'm telling to use.

I've even tried to use the most updated version of the method.

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.layerName = layer_name
options.driverName = 'CSV'
options.layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_WKT', f'GEOMETRY_NAME='the_geom']

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, filename,QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options = options)
```

But again it just create the CSV files with the first layer (amd0) and it's not taking into account the layerOptions I'm specifiying, since for example, the geometry field is called WKT instead of the_geom as I'm stating. I've also tried to include in layerOptions 'LAYER_NAME=adm1' but it raises a warning saying that `dataset .... does not support layer creation option LAYER_NAME`

I've tried this solutions too but they didn't work: [Loading zipped shapefile from URL using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/loading-zipped-shapefile-from-url-using-pyqgis)

Comment: Hi! Could you please separate the issues into two questions? I don't see what exporting a CSV has to do with loading zipped Shapefiles. They seem to be independent issues. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it's fully related, my question is how to convert all sublayers of a shp.zip into independent csv files, either by loading each sublayer independently or by loading the whole shp.zip file and then export each sublayer one by one. That's why I described the whole process I followed. Because actually, loading a shp.zip is pretty easy and straight forward,`QgsVectorLayer("my_polygons_shp.zip")` works fine

Comment: I'd suggest splitting the "full project" into separate issues though as they have little to do with each other. Right now you are getting invalid layers, right? Best first fix that issue and then see what other issues occur further on.

Answer (score 4):

You are specifying `QgsVectorLayer`'s "`path`" (aka "url" or "connection string") parameter wrong.

There are two possible approaches which I explain below. Note how they handle the paths and layernames very differently. I recommend using the `.shp.zip` approach if you are in control of the archive's file name.

## `.shp.zip`

If you are using GDAL 3.1+ you can automagically [load Shapefiles from ZIP archives](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html) if the archive's name is ending in `.shp.zip`.

In that case you can specify the layer to load for the `QgsVectorLayer` by appending a layername (e. g. a basename of a Shapefile: "`foo`" if you have "`foo.*`") to the connection string with `|layername={layername}`.

For example `QgsVectorLayer("/tmp/foo.shp.zip|layername=bar", "name", "ogr")` will try to load `bar.shp` from the root of the `foo.shp.zip` archive.

## `/vsizip/`

To load geodata from within a zipped dataset, in the context of formats that do not have a standard as to how they are zipped, you can use a "[virtual filesystem](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html)" provided by GDAL, in this case `/vsizip/`.

The [linked question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/loading-zipped-shapefile-from-url-using-pyqgis) has working examples.

For example `QgsVectorLayer("/vsizip//tmp/foo.zip/bar.shp", "name", "ogr")` will try to load a Shapefile `bar.shp` from the root of the `foo.zip` archive.

Comment: First of all I have to mention that the path is not wrongly specified, `QgsVectorLayer` can load a `_shp.zip` without any troubles. At least with my version.
I have GDAL 3.0.4 and GIS 3.27.0. I will try to update GDAL and QGIS, and reply if the first option works. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You said that your layers are not valid. `QgsVectorLayer("nonexistant.file")` also "works" but isn't resulting in a valid layer!